# Sending custom telemetry to azure insights

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, telemetry

I have a Java azure function (runtime 3.2.0) where I try to send some custom telemetry. I use the following code

```
TelemetryConfiguration config = TelemetryConfiguration.getActive()
TelemetryClient telemetry = new TelemetryClient(config);

telemetry.trackEvent("Test Event");
telemetry.trackTrace("Test Trace", SeverityLevel.Warning);

telemetry.flush(); // Not sure it is needed
```

When I check config.getInstrumentationKey() is is the correct key for the Application Insights I want to show the custom telemetry. However, I never receive the custom event and trace in my Insights. Also config.isTrackingDisabled() i false and config.getChannel() seems to make sense.

All code examples I have found and in the official documentation as well it seems to be all the code I need. When I use the logger from the ExecutionContext logs appears in Application inside, so my function has access to it. So I suspect I have overlooked some small important fact or there is some configuration of my function that is not set correctly.

Can anybody help me get custom telemetry to work on my java function?

Comment: Try removing telemetry.flush().

Comment: flushing is an asynchronous operation. Try waiting a second of 5 in your code after the call to `flush` to make sure the process gets enough time to send the data.

Comment: @AliasCartellano in azure functions calling flush could be common sense as most of the times the function exists as soon as the code is done.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I have found out that when I run my function locally it actually sends all my custom telemetry to my application insights when I use

`telemetryClient.getContext().setInstrumentationKey("APP INSIGHT INSTRUMENTATION KEY");`

To hard code the instrumentation key of the app insights I want to connect to, which shows that the code is working. However, when I run my function in azure (triggered by a HTTP trigger) I get no telemetry. Anybody has an idea how this can happen?

Comment: Do you have an environment variable (either instrumentation key or connection string) set in your Azure Function?

Comment: Yes we have ApplicationInsights_InstrumentationKey set on the function.